# User input - How to use predefined list

Tags: completing-read

While there are [org-templates](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58890/create-smart-multi-level-headings-with-proper-indentation) creating entire bullet points with content, what I am looking for is a simple user query (similar to `read-string`) where the user can use a pre-defined list of words/phrases to choose from (up/down or left/right arrow keys).

Background:

I am with our IT department and among other things order hardware for our users.  Once an order is out I would like to tell them when their hardware is expected to arrive.  The general text stays the same, but I would like to choose the week's workdays from a list to complete this text snippet.  Plus points, if I can have a second choice based on the first to choose this or next week.  This means when I choose "today" or "tomorrow", it shall not ask for the week.  Likewise choosing "Monday" or "Tuesday" shall fix the second choice to "next week" (since otherwise I could have chosen "today" or "tomorrow" if it were this week).

Simplified result (with choices highlighted):

I ordered your hardware and it is estimated to arrive `Wednesday` `next week`.

Currently I realize that snippet with a script inside the aging AutoKey GTK application, but would love to consolidate what I have there into Emacs.  I already have my phrase templates as well as full-auto scripts in Emacs, but I am struggling to get the user input stuff to work the way I would like to have it.

`read-string` has a history argument, but I am not sure if one can misuse(?) that for what I intend.  Being still fairly new to elisp, maybe there are better or more sophisticated ways to do so.  Since Emacs' built-in help as well as most online resources are notoriously sparse on examples to demonstrate its capabilities, an example would go a long way.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like `completing-read`, maybe via `ivy`. Here's a quick snippet that reuses `calendar-day-name-array` to get the usual names, but you can use your usual service days instead:

```lisp
(require 'calendar)  ; for calendar-day-name-array
(defun my/arrival ()
  "Place an arrival date"
  (interactive)
  (let ((choice (completing-read "Arrival: " (append calendar-day-name-array '("today" "tomorrow")))))
    (pcase choice
      ("today" choice)     ; Return today and tomorrow as-is
      ("tomorrow" choice)
      (other
       (let ((week (completing-read (format "Which %s? " choice) '("this week" "next week"))))
         (format "%s %s" choice week))))))
```

For more flexibility, you can customize the possible arrival days and also add a function to insert your choice at point:

```lisp
(require 'calendar)
(defcustom my/arrivaldays
  (append 
    (or calendar-day-name-array 
       '("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday")) nil)
  "The possible arrival dates of hardware."
  :type '(repeat string))  

(defun my/arrival ()
  "Ask for an arrival date"
  (interactive)
  (let ((choice (completing-read "Arrival: " (append my/arrivaldays '("today" "tomorrow")))))
    (pcase choice
      ("today" choice)     ; Return today and tomorrow as-is
      ("tomorrow" choice)
      (other
       (let ((week (completing-read (format "Which %s? " choice) '("this week" "next week"))))
         (format "%s %s" choice week))))))

(defun my/arrival-insert ()
  "Insert an arrival date at point"
  (interactive)
  (insert (my/arrival)))
```

Comment: I have seen no problems with the Lisp you have posted so far in your recent answers.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the feedback, very appreciated!

Comment: Strangely, this works for me only after I `C-h v` the variable "calendar-day-name-array".  Otherwise after a restart of Emacs (v27.1) it ends up with `completing-read: Symbol’s value as variable is void: calendar-day-name-array`.  Do I need to initialize this variable and/or customize it to work?

Comment: @Phoenix Hm, that's strange. At least on my plattform (Emacs 26.3 on Kubuntu 18.04) It's initialized to the usual days. What's your Emacs version?

Comment: @Zeta, as written in the comment: v27.1.  OS I am using is Fedora 32.

Comment: Did some more testing.  After a restart and loading this "el"-file, positioning point onto "calendar-day-name-array", it will still write the help for "append" with "SEQUENCES" in bold.  After I `C-h v` the variable, it shows what this variable is: `calendar-day-name-array: Array of capitalized strings giving, in order from Sunday, the day names.`  So, something is off here.

Comment: @Phoenix I've tried a workaround with a customization variable that falls back on some predefined days.

Comment: @Zeta, maybe it is my version of Emacs, but copy'n'pasting the second part will fail outright upon starting Emacs with `Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/Portable/janms/.emacs.d/init.el’:` and the error is the same message.  If I can avoid using this pre-defined list and create one of my own, maybe that will solve it.  I just never managed to create a list.  Another thing seemingly more complicated than in other scripting languages, like bash, PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115333/discussion-between-zeta-and-phoenix).